# Conversion of UTF-16 csv file to UTF-8 csv file works in python but not in excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel, csv

I'm trying to convert a csv file named "kyoto_restaurants.csv" from UTF-16 to UTF-8.
This file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mNLIox0RGuv7yfhrqemBLkwXX9P5fQbP/view?usp=sharing).

Here is the code:

```
from csv import reader
from csv import writer

with open('kyoto_restaurants.csv', encoding='utf-16') as file:
    read_file = reader(file)
    rows = list(read_file)

with open('kyoto_restaurants_utf8.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as file:
    write_file = writer(file)
    for row in rows:
        write_file.writerow(row)

with open('kyoto_restaurants_utf8.csv', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    read_file = reader(file)
    rows = list(read_file)
    print(rows[0])
    print(rows[1])
    print(rows[2])
```

As you can observe from the printout, the converted file "kyoto_restaurants_utf8.csv" appears to be good.  All of the English and Japanese character appear to be good.

However, when opening "kyoto_restaurants_utf8.csv" using Excel, the Japanese characters appear all wrong.

From the Python3 print output, the second record is (all good):

```
['1', 'Orudeidainingurajou  ', 'オールデイダイニング ラジョウ', 'Kyoto', 'Buffet style', 'Cafe', '￥4000～￥4999', '￥2000～￥2999', '3.39', '3.2', '3.38', '56', '34.9861751483108', '135.761313932311']
```

From Excel, the second record is (the Japanese is all wrong):
(click to see larger)
[image]

My question is: what can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel does not expect a csv file to have UTF-8 encoding.  To open a UTF-8 file, do the following (in Microsoft 365 Excel):

1. Open a blank workbook.
2. Click on the "Data" ribbon.
3. In the "Get & Transform Data" section, click on "From Text/CSV".
4. In the "Import Data" window, select the utf-8 encoded file and click "Import".
5. Select under "File Origin": "65001: Unicode (UTF-8)".
6. Click on "Transform Data".
7. Click on "Close & Load".

The file should be loaded correctly into the excel workbook.